# How to install SSL certificate on my local machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl-certificate

I have a MVC4 project in which I want to enable `[RequireHttps]` filter attribute for secure communication. But when I enable that filter attribute it gives me an error:

> SSL Connection Error.

I guess, I have to install SSL certificate on my local machine. Can someone please let me know the steps how can I install certificate on my local machine to prevent the existing issue on my application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self-signed certificate.

As by the [IIS 7 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753127(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

#### To use the UI

- Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).
- In Features view, double-click Server Certificates.
- In the Actions pane, click Create Self-Signed Certificate.
- On the Create Self-Signed Certificate page, type a friendly name for the certificate in the Specify a friendly name for the certificate box, and then click OK.

For other versions please consult [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/).

Answer (score 0):

> Install the Certificate Authority #
>
> On every OS there are different ways, how to install the Certificate
>   Authority. Please see this post to find out how to install it on your
>   OS. Note that for Firefox you need an additional installation as they
>   use their own certificate authority store.
>
> In all cases you need to install the root.cer and not the server.cer –
>   took me some time to figure this out.
>
> After installing it and restarting the browser, the ceritificate is
>   now valid and you can test everything related to https on your local
>   machine.

https://justmarkup.com/articles/2018-05-31-https-valid-certificate-local-domain/